# 'database' is compressed but does not reside in a read-only database or filegroup

Tags: sql-server

Q&A: A user of our software reported a SQL Server Error. The software had been running fine previously. The error is:

> The file at C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL14.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL\DATA{database}.mdf is compressed but does not reside in a read-only database
>   or filegroup. The file must be decompressed. CREATE DATABASE failed.
>   Some file names listed could not be created. Check related errors.

What's the fix please?

*Posting as a Q&A* as I couldn't find a step-by step answer on StackOverflow and Windows is now recommending file compression when your disk is nearly full.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

As stated [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/231347/description-of-support-for-sql-server-databases-on-compressed-volumes), SQL Server databases are not supported on compressed volumes.

In this case, Windows had recommended compression to make more room on their hard drive, so they did just that.

The fix was:

1. Go to 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL14.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL' ('MSSQL14.SQLEXPRESS' might be different, depending on your SQL Server Version).
2. Right click the 'DATA' folder (i.e. the folder that contains .mdf files)
3. Choose 'Properties'
4. Click the 'Advanced' button
5. Uncheck the 'Compress contents to save disk space' checkbox
6. Click 'Ok'.

Comment: Just a reminder, step 1 & 2 is optional if your mdf file is not reside in the default location

Comment: It worked for me, thank you very much.